# React-testing-library test not waiting for data populated by Apollo MockedProvider

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-apollo

I am trying to write a simple test for a component that fetches data through `useQuery`. I can see that the data is properly mocked, unfortunately the spec is failing.

This is the provider:

```
export const WritingsProvider = ({children}) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(WRITINGS_QUERY)
```

This is the component:

```
const WritingsWithData = () => {
  const { data } = useWritings()
```

This is the test:

```
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing'
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Writings', () => {
  const Component = () => (
    <MockedProvider
      mocks={[writingsQueryMocked]}
      addTypename={false}
      defaultOptions={
        {
          watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' },
          query: { fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' }
        }
      }
    >
      <Writings />
    </MockedProvider>
  )
  it('displays writings', async () => {
    render(<Component />)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

    expect(screen.getByText('foo-short-description')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

If I `console.log` data from `useQuery`, I can see the writings populated. Unfortunately the test doesn't wait for them.

I get following error message:

```
Unable to find an element with the text: foo-short-description. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

I tried debug():

```
Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>
```

Nothing is rendered. But the writings (data from query) are there:

```
console.log
    ### writings [
      {
        slug: 'test',
        title: 'test',
        shortDescription: 'foo-short-description',
        image: 'foo-url',
        id: 'foo-1'
      }
    ]
```

I've tried this too:

```
  it('displays writings', async () => {
    render(<Component />)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0))

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('foo-short-description')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
  })
```

but still failing.

Could someone help me to understand what's going on? how can I debug? The documentation says:

> To test how your component is rendered after its query completes, you
> can await a zero-millisecond timeout before performing your checks.
> This delays the checks until the next "tick" of the event loop, which
> gives MockedProvider an opportunity to populate the mocked result:

But it's not happening. Versions that I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.8",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-code-auto-typing": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom-confetti": "^0.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "react-typical": "^0.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: The unit test fails with _what_ error? You do not have to await a new Promise. You can just use a `waitFor` or better yet just do `await screen.findByText()`. Also, did you try to use `debug` and see the DOM content being printed?

Comment: I tried debug (updated question). It's like empty.

Comment: Ok. Can you show what the ‘Writings’ component looks like ?

Comment: finally found. Within writings, I had a component with a NavLink, and I didn't have the MemoryRouter yet in my spec. I was too focus on apollo mocking issues. Your hint having a look at the writings component help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: That’s great. Glad that you found it finally 